# JPS results and hdfs admin report is different

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs, bigdata, hadoop-yarn

Here is my jps results on master node.

> NameNode
>   SecondaryNameNode

And slave node jps output

> Datanode

### If i look at the jps result, it seems everything is godd but when i run  hdfs dfsadmin -report , only shows datanode. But jps says also namenode is working. Also i can't reach to namenode via web UI

Live datanodes (1):

> ```
> > Name: 172.31.7.44:50010 (ip-172-31-7-44.us-east-2.compute.internal)
> > Hostname: ip-172-31-7-44.us-east-2.compute.internal Decommission
> > Status : Normal Configured Capacity: 10724814848 (9.99 GB) DFS Used:
> > 4096 (4 KB) Non DFS Used: 4309471232 (4.01 GB) DFS Remaining:
> > 6415339520 (5.97 GB) DFS Used%: 0.00% DFS Remaining%: 59.82%
> > Configured Cache Capacity: 0 (0 B) Cache Used: 0 (0 B) Cache
> > Remaining: 0 (0 B) Cache Used%: 100.00% Cache Remaining%: 0.00%
> > Xceivers: 1 Last contact: Wed Jun 12 11:29:29 UTC 2019
> ```

```
[root@ip-***.***.*** ~]# sudo netstat -antlp
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      921/sshd         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50010           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5439/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50075           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5439/java        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50020           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5439/java
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:43211         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5439/java        
tcp        0      0 172.31.7.44:52802       178.128.156.238:2700    ESTABLISHED 6423/c1c3mki454jg
tcp        0    232 172.31.7.44:22          212.156.0.106:38724     ESTABLISHED 5214/sshd: ec2-user
tcp        0      0 172.31.7.44:39966       172.31.11.123:9000      ESTABLISHED 5439/java
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      921/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::13562                :::*                    LISTEN      5563/java        
tcp6       0      0 :::34371                :::*                    LISTEN      5563/java  
tcp6       0      0 :::8040                 :::*                    LISTEN      5563/java    
tcp6       0      0 :::8042                 :::*                    LISTEN      5563/java
tcp6       0      0 172.31.7.44:34371       172.31.11.123:58678     ESTABLISHED 5563/java
tcp6       0      0 172.31.7.44:39134       172.31.11.123:8031      ESTABLISHED 5563/java
```

notes:I removed firewall and permissions. There's not any error log in namenode log.

Do you know how can i resolve this issue?

Comment: `hdfs dfsadmin` commands talk to the namenode on the RPC port.  What does `sudo netstat -antlp` show on the namenode host?

Comment: editted netstat output

Comment: Are you sure this is the NameNode host?  This looks like a DataNode and NodeManager based on the ports.